# Is there an easy way to transform ExtJS 4 MVC application to ExtJS DeftJS MVC?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am looking for an easy way to transform an ExtJS app that already uses ExtJS 4 MVC based  architecture to an ExtJS app which uses [DeftJS](http://deftjs.org/) in order to use benefits of dependency injection provided by this framework.

In ExtJS MVC we have one controller but multiple views associated with it. However DeftJS suggests using ViewController concept i.e. one controller per view. This is the main problem with transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view in your app doesn't necessarily need a dedicated ViewController in Deft JS. In many cases, a single ViewController can manage a set of views. In your case, even if you have only one controller, you can still transform your app in to Deft JS app. First, start with your Application.js file, and add the injection configuration. Then, edit your controller to make it a ViewController. Depending the size of your app, it may take some time, especially for the components event handlers, but you'll get there. Phoenix is a great reference app that will answer most of your questions:

https://github.com/deftjs/Examples/tree/master/phoenix-example-app

If you would like to use Sencha Cmd, use this example instead:

https://github.com/deftjs/Examples/tree/master/phoenix-cmd